# Is it possible to query a user-specified column name without resorting to dynamic SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to implement an API with the following signature:

```
public static List<string> SearchDatabase(
    string column,
    string value);
```

The implementation of the API needs to construct an SQL `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` clause that uses a column name specified in the `column` parameter.

The query:

```
string query =
    string.Format(
        "SELECT Name, @Column " +
        "FROM Db1 " +
        "INNER JOIN Db2 ON Db1.Id = Db2.Id " +
        "WHERE @Column = @Value");
```

The SQL command and parameters:

```
SqlCommand selectCmd =
    new SqlCommand(
        query,
        connection);
selectCmd.CommandTimeout = SqlCommandTimeout;
selectCmd.Parameters.AddRange(
    new SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@Column", column),
    new SqlParameter("@Value", value)
});
```

And I execute it like this:

```
SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlDataReader.Read())
{
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that `sqlDataReader` doesn't return any rows, so I don't go into the `while` loop above.

However, if I change the last line of the query above from:

```
"WHERE @Column = @Value");
```

to

```
"WHERE Vendor = @Value");
```

(i.e. hardcode the column name to 'Vendor') then it works.

My understanding from research I have done is that it's not possible to pass column names as parameters, but only values we are querying on.  But, it does appear to let me use the `@Column` parameter in the `SELECT` clause, just not the `WHERE` clause.

I don't want to resort to dynamic SQL because of the issues with SQL injection.  Is there another way around this?

Comment: Couldn't you just do a `string query = string.Format("SELECT Name, " + column + " FROM Db1 INNER JOIN Db2 ON Db1.Id = Db2.Id WHERE "+Column+" = @Value");`? ObWarning: SQL-Injection!

Comment: @Ocaso - Yep, SQL injection is what I'm trying to avoid here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately table names, column names cannot be parametrized. Because you know the structure of the table you could have a whitelist of possible column names in this parameter and then use string concatenation for it to avoid SQL injection:

```
"WHERE " + Sanitize(column) + " = @Value");
```

Comment: Yep it's a solution, but not ideal.  Each time I add new columns to my database, I will probably have to update the implementation of `Sanitize()`.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat, you could use ADO.NET to query your database once (for example at application startup) in order to read the schema of the table and obtain all the possible column names for it and store this whitelist for the entire life-time of the application which will be used by the Sanitize function.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: It may not be ideal, but it's your only choice.

Comment: This solution worked best for me - queried the columns up front and constructed a whitelist, and then used dynamic SQL in conjunction with the whitelist to prevent SQL injection.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with dynamic SQL as long as you escape the column name correctly:

```
string query = string.Format(
    "SELECT Name, {0} " +
    "FROM Db1 " +
    "INNER JOIN Db2 ON Db1.Id = Db2.Id " +
    "WHERE {0} = @Value",
    Delimit(column));
```

where...

```
public static string Delimit(string name) {

    if(name == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    } else if(name.Length == 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("name");
    }

    return "[" + name.Replace("]", "]]") + "]";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep parameters and implement the select as a case statement matching on different values for column name. You may need to cast values if the columns are of different types.

```
 Select case 
         when @column = 'UserName' then username
         when @column = 'Email' then email 
         Else firstname End as Column
 From MyTable
 Where value = @vendor
```

However, I don't see the point in this, just return all columns and pick the one you are interested in using the result set in C# (if it's feasible).

Comment: Thanks - can you elaborate on your last point about returning all columns?

Comment: You mean `select *` and increase network and db-server load? I think that's a bad idea.

Comment: I mean unless your joining on column name dynamically, just do `select db1.*` and in your reader use `reader[columnName]` to dyamically return a specific column.

Comment: @hemal it entirely depends on the data. Returning a single row, then it's nearer here nor there with a handful of columns. You can also cache the single call and poke out values from subsequent calls. It all depends on the nature of the problem. Sometimes the easy solution is the best solution.

Comment: @TheCodeKing agree with your point that it depends on usecase (everything always does). But I would not recommend it as the initial approach and definitely am able to see a point in selecting individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot parametrise column names like that, not in SQL Server.

To avoid building a dynamic query, you could use a CASE expression like this:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  CASE @Column
    WHEN 'Age' THEN Age
    WHEN 'Weight' THEN Weight
    …
  END
…
```

Note, however, that the various possible columns' types should be implicitly compatible with one another in this case (poor pun intended).

Comment: But that means I would need to update the query if a new column is added, right?

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: Yes, I'm afraid. Unless you ask your colleague to save you the trouble. (Just joking, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the column name has already been validated? If not you can add extra validation by adding a `select 1 from <column-names-table> where <column-name-column> = @column`.

If your predicate is always `=` then you don't need to select `@Column`. The extra effort required in populating client side data structure is trivial.

EDIT: Instead of validating column name on each call, @Darin's comment to "2011-09-16 07:24:34Z" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441344/is-it-possible-to-query-a-user-specified-column-name-without-resorting-to-dynamic/7441372#7441372) of one time initialization is better.

Comment: Sometimes the query is `WHERE <column-name-column> LIKE "%@value%"`